# Using ninject.extensions.factory - What happens in the root class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am new to using dependency injection, and am trying on Ninject. As I am exploring the function of Ninject Factory, there is something that puzzled me.

From https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface,

```
public class Foo
{
    readonly IBarFactory barFactory;

    public Foo(IBarFactory barFactory)
    {
        this.barFactory = barFactory;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var bar = this.barFactory.CreateBar();
        ...
    }
}

public interface IBarFactory
{
    Bar CreateBar();
}
```

We can create Bar using

```
       var bar = this.barFactory.CreateBar();
```

But what approach should we take to create an instance of Foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do exactly one `kernel.Get<>()` in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) of your application.